# On select of dropdown option give specific answer in the div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a helpdesk & initially trying to input pre defined selected question with their solution. I'm stuck where i need to display different solution to different question depending on the question selected from the drop down list.

Please Help

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HelpDesk</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Helpdesk</h1>
        <hr>
        <form align="center">
            Select Question Type : 
            <select>
                <option>Select Query Type</option>
                <option id="1">Internet not working</option>
                <option id="2">Cannot download file</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net mvc?

Comment: No Sir. We will need to do it through HTML only.Because we will give the solution i.e by editing the code in the static page only.

Comment: So you will save all the questions and the answer in one single html page?

Comment: Yes Sir. This is the present requirement.

Comment: Not really 'best practice' but ok. You're aware of how much work needs to be done if you want to update your answers/questions?

Comment: Yes... But we just starting with it on trial basis. If this works out then we will go to database & fetch results from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82780/discussion-between-ak-56-and-greenhoorn).

Comment: Alright, I edited my post with the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your question and solution on the HTML itself, you can try the solution given below.

HTML

```
 <h1 align="center">Helpdesk</h1>
  <hr>
    <form align="center">
     Select Question Type : 
    <select>
      <option>Select Query Type</option>
      <option value="1">Internet not working</option>
      <option value="2">Cannot download file</option>
    </select>
    <div class="results">
    <div class="ans" data-ans="1">Internet solution</div>
    <div class="ans" data-ans="2">download solution</div>
</div>
</form>
```

JS

```
(function(){
 var ele = document.querySelectorAll('form select');
 var result = document.querySelectorAll('.results .ans');
 ele[0].addEventListener('change',function(e){
    var matchVal = this.value.toString();

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(result,function(val){   
        val.style.display = 'none';
        if(val.getAttribute('data-ans') == matchVal){
            val.style.display = 'block';
        }
    })
});

})()
```

Here is a working copy in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vpwj3a42/

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onChange` event to listen to value changes and react accordingly.

```js
function showAnswer(id) {
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = answers[id];
}

var answers = {
  js: 'JavaScript is a scripting language for computers. It is often run in web browser applications to create dynamic content like a popup message or a live clock. It is not related to and is different from the programming language Java.',
  html: 'HyperText Markup Language (HTML) is a Programming language for creating webpages. Webpages are usually viewed in a web browser. They can include writing, links, pictures, and even sound and video. HTML is used to mark and describe each of these kinds of content so the web browser can show them correctly.',
  css: 'Cascading Style Sheets, or CSS, are a way to change the look of HTML and XHTML web pages. CSS was designed by the W3C, and is supported well by most modern web browsers. The current version of CSS is CSS 2. CSS version 3 is currently being worked on. It will introduce new properties like border-radius.'
};
```

```html
Select Query Type:
<select onChange="showAnswer(this.value)">
  <option value="js">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="html">HTML</option>
  <option value="css">CSS</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div id="answer">JavaScript is a scripting language for computers. It is often run in web browser applications to create dynamic content like a popup message or a live clock. It is not related to and is different from the programming language Java.</div>
```

Comment: Sir thank you for the code. But the solution will be long description depending on different questions. So how should i modify the code ? i.e Suppose for option 1 there are 3 different steps & option 2 there will be different solution all together. How to do that ?

Comment: You already have the solutions stored somewhere, right? If it's in an array or a DB you can fetch them in the `showAnswer(id)` and populate the solutions `<div>` accordingly.

Comment: Sir right now i dnt have db or array. We just trying simple trial for this where we need to store the answer for questions in the same html page & call the desired solution depending on the question selected in the drop down box .

Comment: @AK_56 I modified the answer to store some pre-defined answers in a JS object.

Comment: Thank You Sir. Really easy to understand.

Comment: I like this answer although you're getting performance issues if the FAQ gets bigger :)

Comment: Thought about this way, yet it gets awkward if one wants to insert anything besides textformat in strings. For example some <h1>Internet</h1><p>blablabla</p>. Yet a solid solution.

Comment: Same question came to my mind as i might want to add images n all

Comment: you can use @JavaScipt answer.

Comment: Well, I dislike both concepts - since all the HTML is there all the time, even if we never see it. There would be a neat solution, yet currently I lack the time to do it. You create seperate HTML files for each answers, on select change you grab the correct file by AJAX and create a div on the fly. This spares initial space and traffic. If you have some time to wait, I can deliever it later today after work.

Comment: Sure Sir ! It will be great help. Is there any way to add video links or something because we just thought of it & looking to add it.

Comment: It saddens me to get beaten by a copy of my answer, but as long as it helps you - all is fine. For different questions please use different/new topics.

Comment: Sure Sir will do that

Answer (score 1):

## What do we want to achieve?

Depending on a select option (type of question) we want to show a different solution/answer. The questions are meant to be stored in HTML and not being outsourced (according to the initial post).

### Solution

The solution would be to store each solution in a different outsourced HTML file. So one can edit and maintain the solutions in known HTML structure and also maintain each solution seperately. Furthermore we do not keep all the solutions in our DOM anymore, which saves traffic and bits.

### Requirements

For each solution we create one HTML file to it. [image]

#### index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HelpDesk</title>

        <script>
            //This is out simple AJAX routine to not overload it by any framework.
            //If you are already using jQuery, just use $.get()
            ;var AJAX = {
                getXmlDoc: function(){return ((window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))},

                //u:=url, f:=callback, c:=any param to pass to callback
                Get: function(u, f, c){
                    var tDoc = this.getXmlDoc();

                    tDoc.open('GET', u, true);
                    tDoc.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if (tDoc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && tDoc.status === 200) f(tDoc, c);
                        else f(null, c)
                    };

                    tDoc.send();
                }
            };

            //This namespace holds our functionality
            ;var Answers = {
                mDefaultType: '_Default', //The type of our default/fallback answer

                //Our select on change event
                //e:=dom element (=select)
                _onChange: function(e){
                    var tF = e.value + '.html'; //The filename to fetch

                    //Now we are loading the correct content from the outsourced html file
                    AJAX.Get(tF, function(r, f){
                        if (r){
                            //Fetching our solution div
                            var tD = document.querySelector('#Solution');
                            if (tD) tD.innerHTML = r.responseText
                        }
                        else console.log('_onChange(): File not found "' + f + '"')
                    }, tF);
                },

                //We assign the change event to the select
                Init: function(){
                    var tS = document.querySelector('#selType');
                    if (tS) tS.onchange = function(){Answers._onChange(this)}
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'Answers.Init()'>
        <h1 align="center">Helpdesk</h1>
        <hr>
        <form align="center">
            Select Question Type : 
            <!-- Here we need an id to assign the javascript event -->
            <select id = 'selType'>
                <option>Select Query Type</option>
                <!-- We do not require id on options, yet values -->
                <option value = 'Solution1'>Internet not working</option>
                <option value = 'Solution2'>Cannot download file</option>
            </select>

            <!-- Here we are storing our anwers -->
            <div id = 'Solution'><!-- Filled by AJAX --></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Solution1.html

```
<h1>Solution 1</h1>
<p>Hello there, I am solution #1</p>
```

#### Solution2.html

```
<h1>Solution 2</h1>
<p>Hello there, I am solution #2</p>
```

Comment: Sir i'm not able to get the result from the Solution1. html file

Comment: Are you getting any message in your console?

Comment: Nope.. The div tag remains blank

Comment: Well the console not the div (press F12 and move to console tab). Try to recheck the typing of the filenames and keep in mind that the option value needs to match the filename without extension (value = Solution, fielname = Solution.html).

Comment: Filename & option value name are same

Comment: Sir it's giving error of AJAX line 21   tDoc.send();  XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Comment: Sounds like a crossdomain call to me. Be aware to try it in an actual website and not in the filesystem (file://).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82798/discussion-between-ak-56-and-javascript).